# Different configurations per folder on typescript with vscode

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have a project with the following structure:

```
/
-tsconfig.json // root TSConfig
projects/
| | project1/
| | |-tsconfig.json //  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json"
| | project2/
| | |-tsconfig.json //  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json"
```

the root `tsconfig.json` has most of the configurations across both projects; however, **project1** has some strict configurations (like `noStrictAny` or `strictNullChecks`) that are not present on project2.

This is fine when we build stuff from the command line; project1 has the extra checks while project2 is more lenient as expected. However, VSCode doesn't seem to understand that; if I open a project1 file, it won't have the extra strictness that comes from its local tsconfig. For that matter, if we open `project1` in a new window, the strictness applies to the IDE just fine.

Is it possible to configure vscode so that it can recognize 'subprojects' with different configurations like that? Or are we stuck with opening the project in a new window?

Comment: If you have multiple projects try https://nx.dev/angular: Might not help with this exact problem, but they have good solutions for monorepos

Comment: Did you report issue in vscode github repo? If not, you probably should.